# Copy datatable to another datatable in oracle while preserving changes and existing rows

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable

I have to transfer data from a data table to oracle table.
But one of the column is primary key, so when I try to execute my code for second time it shows error - Unique constraint violated.

Is there any class or method for datatable ,such that when I copy the data into datatable it checks internally for if the data already exists update the table and if new data insert into the table.

Comment: You want to use the id's of the datatable to populate your Oracle db?  This seems like a bad idea.  Just generate some parameterized sql and do inserts.  For more than that, perhaps showing the code you are using would be helpful.

Comment: You can use a `MERGE` in order to `INSERT` when no match is found and `UPDATE` when a match is found. I'm not sure if it's entirely appropriate for the scenario you are describing though.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: @Drumbeg I was totally just going to upvote your answer. :)  Merge requires generating some sql in c#, but seems like a decent way to go.

Comment: @paqogomez Thanks! I removed the answer as wasn't sure if it would be a great fit in this case. As you suggest, I think `MERGE` requires a `SELECT` source in  order to work.

Comment: I was trying to merge datatables from sql server and oracle and I get conflicting datatypes as the error. Any suggestions on how to handle it.

Comment: use a db link with your merge/select

Comment: How to do that @OldProgrammer